# Get the closest sibling of the data in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking the price with class "onward" should take the data "I want this data "

```
    <span class="onward">4518</span>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="select_fly">
          <form>
            I want this data
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    $(document).on('click', '.onward', function(){
       var owner = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.select_fly').html();
       console.log(owner);
    });
```

But for me owner is coming as "undefined" can anyone help me how to get data " I want this data"

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var owner = $(this).next('table').find('td.select_fly').html();
```

So your JS will be :

```js
     
        $(document).on('click', '.onward', function(){
              var owner =  $(this).next('table').find('td.select_fly').html();
              alert(owner);
        });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <span class="onward">4518</span>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="select_fly">
    <form>
    I want this data
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

If you want to have only the text, then

```
   var owner =  $(this).next('table').find('td.select_fly form').html();
```

This will give only

> I want this data

Comment: you have conflicting traverses

Comment: @charlietfl there was a mismatch the query selectors. Now I've updated it. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Try the code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.onward', function(){
     var owner = $(this).next('table').find('td.select_fly').html();
console.log(owner);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gc79gsbw/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your javascript to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.onward', function(){
 var owner = $(this).next('table').find('form').html();
console.log(owner);
});
```

Please find a JSBin for the issue [here](http://jsbin.com/qusifiyoqa/1/edit)